# TabBar with "drag" for iOS 5

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios5

I want to develop an application that has a NavigationBar on top, a TableView in the middle and on the bottom I want to create this sort of TabBar. When I drag the inner smaller rectangle I want to change the content of the TableView. So basically I want it to act like a regular TabBar, where for each small component I change my view (but without changing the NavigationBar).

What would be the best way to approach this. I am kind of new to developing iOS application. Thanks

I want something like this:

[image]

Comment: Why wouldnt you want to change the navigation bar? I think the way for you to go is create a TabBar Application, with each Tab having its own NavigationController. When you change Tabs, different tableviews are shown. dont use one and change the content

Comment: Yes, I will show different tableviews, but I want my tab bar to have that format (something similar to the old HTC Sense if you know, where you drag or click, and it changes the screen)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way of doing that is to create a custom component. There is no "drag effect" with UITabBar.

What you should do is subclassing UIView creating 5 UIButtons inside and one "mobile" UIView which will be the size of the UIButton.

Of course you'll need images for all of these component (but that's not really hard to do).

They you can code your custom behavior inside this subclass.

Comment: Why exactly do I have to create 5 UIButtons buttons?

Comment: If you ask about the type UIButton, I said that because it would made your custom slider clickable as you can addTarget and Selector to a UIButton.

Comment: For the number, it can be 5,4,3... I said 5 because UITabBar has a maximum of 5 section

Comment: Could you point me to some tutorial, how exactly can I subclass UIView and how can I create a custom component? Can I still use the user interface? Or it will be all done in code? Or maybe a tutorial where it shows me how I can create a custom component.

Comment: You will be able to use Intrface Builder but you cannot change parameters of your custom component through IB. Basically you will put a custom UIView in Interface Builder and set the class to be "MyCustomView".

Then you'll need to override touches method to detect when the user is touching the movable view. And you'll do the drag movement. When toucheEnded, you'll need to put your movable view in the correct position with implicit animation.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/1768/how-to-make-a-custom-uiview-a-5-star-rating-view

Comment: This is more clear now, I have one more question. How can I set my main controller to respond to the interactions I do with my custom controller. For instance, after I slide my component to where I want to navigate, how do I let the controller know. Do I need to keep a reference to the main controller?

Comment: Yes it'll be like regular component, you can create methods like addTarget: action: etc.. to your custom component.

I guess you can maybe subclass UIControl to have more code. See on documentation if UIControl allow subclassing.

Comment: I have used the interface builder to draw my custom component. I have also created a subclass of UIControl and associated with my view. I have created three UIButtons for my three sections and another one that I will drag on the slider. So now I need to connect these as outlets and just handle the touches event? An how will I be able to use this in my future applications? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Totally forgot about the drag effect. You won't have that there. But at least it would look similar...

If you are targeting iOS5 you could use a UISegmentedControl and style it with some images.

Have a look at the "Customizing UISegmentedControl" section in the [User Interface Customization in iOS 5 tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/4344/user-interface-customization-in-ios-5)

You basically create an image for each possible state (selected - selected, unselected - selected, selected - unselected and unselected - unselected) and use the new [`UIAppearance`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIAppearance_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIAppearance) methods to create a custom appearance.

```
UIImage *segmentSelected = 
    [[UIImage imageNamed:@"segcontrol_sel.png"] 
        resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 15, 0, 15)];
UIImage *segmentUnselected = 
    [[UIImage imageNamed:@"segcontrol_uns.png"] 
        resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 15, 0, 15)];
UIImage *segmentSelectedUnselected = 
    [UIImage imageNamed:@"segcontrol_sel-uns.png"];
UIImage *segUnselectedSelected = 
    [UIImage imageNamed:@"segcontrol_uns-sel.png"];
UIImage *segmentUnselectedUnselected = 
    [UIImage imageNamed:@"segcontrol_uns-uns.png"];

[[UISegmentedControl appearance] setBackgroundImage:segmentUnselected 
    forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[[UISegmentedControl appearance] setBackgroundImage:segmentSelected 
    forState:UIControlStateSelected barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

[[UISegmentedControl appearance] setDividerImage:segmentUnselectedUnselected 
    forLeftSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal 
    rightSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal 
    barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[[UISegmentedControl appearance] setDividerImage:segmentSelectedUnselected 
    forLeftSegmentState:UIControlStateSelected 
    rightSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal 
    barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[[UISegmentedControl appearance] 
    setDividerImage:segUnselectedSelected 
    forLeftSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal 
    rightSegmentState:UIControlStateSelected 
    barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately I want the dragging effect also.

Answer (score 0):

So basically u want to reload table on each segment clicked,

## create 3 NSMutable array and fill them with data.

suppose arrOne,arrTwo and arrThree,

## do these things

```
  - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section  {   int returnValue = 0;
    if(segment.tag == 0)        returnValue = [arrOne count]-1;     else 
    if(segment.tag == 1)        returnValue = [arrTwo count]-1;         else 
    if(segment.tag == 2)            returnValue = [arrTwo count]-1;         return
  returnValue;

  }



- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    if(segment.tag == 0)
        cell.text = [arrOne  objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    else    if(segment.tag == 1)
        cell.text = [arrTwo  objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        else    if(segment.tag == 2)
            cell.text = [arrThree  objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
```

## and each segment pressed:

```
[tblObject reloadData];
```

Comment: I understand, but I am more interested in how I can create the custom component, I want the dragging effect.